# redirect from htaccess (https to http)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I used this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(shop|university)(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule !^(shop|university)(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I want redirect http to https two categories (shop and university), other i want redirect to http

BUT, after installation of the rules to all https transfers me on http but from universiti and shop puts on the main page. what could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  


    RewriteEngine On

   #https to http    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(shop|university)/      
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]


   #http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(shop|university)/      
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]



</IfModule>
```

Comment: when i used it, i have MORE errors: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/shop/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.4'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.